# Finch Sound Engine Memory Leak

Tags: xcode4, memory-leaks, finch

I want to access some sounds in different classes and can be read and change the pitch values of each sound in multiple classes. Then i use `extern FISound *mySound` in my application delegate methods and loaded them in my view controller. It is working like a charm but the problem is there is an always memory leaks for `[FIDecoder decodeSampleAtPath:error]`

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
FISample,1  0x76e9030   32 Bytes    Musizs  -[FIDecoder decodeSampleAtPath:error:]
NSConcreteData,1    0x76e7100   32 Bytes    Foundation  +[NSData(NSData) allocWithZone:]
NSConcreteData,1    0x737b080   32 Bytes    Foundation  +[NSData(NSData) allocWithZone:]
FISample,1  0x76e81c0   32 Bytes    Musizs  -[FIDecoder decodeSampleAtPath:error:]
```

Is somebody have problem like that?? Thank you.

Comment: ok i release the sample and data after writing it to the buffer at the end of the 

    - (id) initWithSample: (FISample*) sample error: (NSError**) error
    .......
    ...
    ....
    duration = [sample duration];
    [sample.data release];
    [sample release];
    return self;

working ok for the moment but i am not sure if it is logical or not. No leaks for the moment and working ok.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The library code looks good to me, even after checking with Instruments. Can you post a short sample code that exhibits the leak? Also, how do you add the manual `release` calls to the source? The library uses ARC, so that manual memory management calls should be illegal. Do you use the library the right way, by referencing the whole Xcode project, or do you just import the “naked” source files?

Comment: i import the naked source files and make a library in the project and then use it. I understand what you mean. Because my project don't use ARC problem occurs. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

XCode 4 detects many possible memory leaks with Finch.  This is because 
Finch is not properly naming its methods according to memory management guidelines.

Methods that create objects must begin their method name
with "new", "alloc", "copy", or "mutableCopy".

See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

For example, decodeSampleAtPath should be renamed to "allocDecodeSampleAtPath".
And anything that uses this method must then release it.

There are many methods in Finch that don't do this, and they all should be fixed.

Comment: The method names are fine, `decodeSampleAtPath:` returns an autoreleased object. The library uses ARC, maybe that’s what gave you the impression that the returned object is not autoreleased?